# Why can't a function that has heap memory passed to it delete it in c++?

Tags: c++

I tried to make a function that could delete memory on a int pointer. Unfortunately, it did not succeed. I feel like I made a mistake. Can someone help me find it?

```
#include <iostream>
void clean(int * x){
  delete x;
  x=nullptr;
}
int main() {
  int * integer = new int;
  clean(integer);
  if(integer){
    std::cout<<"Clean Failed\n";
  }
  else{
    std::cout<<"Clean Succeeded\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: `x=nullptr;` only modifies the local pointer variable. It does not have any effect on the variable declared in `main`

Comment: Change `int * x` to `int *& x` to see a different result

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank You! I thought about turning it into a reference, but I was confused how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `clean` function actually does deallocate the memory.
But it doesn't update the pointer passed to it.

Change `clear` to accept the pointer by refernce to fix the problem:

```
void clean(int *& x) {
    delete x;
    x = nullptr;
}
```

Some more information:

Parameters in C/C++ are actually always passed by value. In your original code, the pointer value (i.e. the address stored in it) is passed to `clean`.
When you change it to `int *& x` what is passed is a refernce to the pointer (which is actually similar semantic-wise to `int ** x`). I.e. it's the address of the pointer itself, not the address stored in it. Using the address of the pointer, the function `clear` can modify it and set it to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever something is passed to a function, it is copied to it.
Here, an int* is copied to `clean`.
Changing its value will not change it in the calling function.

Like this for example:

```cpp
void func(int a) { ++a; }
int main() {
  int a = 10;
  func(a);
  // a is still 10
  return 0;
}
```

So you have to send a pointer to pointer to change its value. We use references in C++:

```cpp
void clean(int*& x){
  delete x;
  x = nullptr;
}
clean(integer)
```

Which is internally:

```cpp
void clean(int** x){
  delete *x;
  *x = nullptr;
}
clean(&integer)
```